# Difference between ANY(ARRAY[..]) vs ANY(VALUES (), () ..) in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, where-clause

I am trying to workout query optimisation on id. Not sure which one way should I use. Below is the query plan using `explain` and cost wise looks similar.

```
1. explain (analyze, buffers) SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = ANY (ARRAY['00e289b0-1ac8-451f-957f-e00bc289148e'::uuid,...]);

QUERY PLAN:
    Index Scan using table1_pkey on table1  (cost=0.42..641.44 rows=76 width=835) (actual time=0.258..2.603 rows=76 loops=1)
    Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{00e289b0-1ac8-451f-957f-e00bc289148e,...}'::uuid[]))
    Buffers: shared hit=231 read=73
    Planning Time: 0.487 ms
    Execution Time: 2.715 ms)


2. explain (analyze, buffers) SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = ANY (VALUES ('00e289b0-1ac8-451f-957f-e00bc289148e'::uuid),...);

QUERY PLAN:
Nested Loop  (cost=1.56..644.10 rows=76 width=835) (actual time=0.058..0.297 rows=76 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=304
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1.14..1.90 rows=76 width=16) (actual time=0.049..0.060 rows=76 loops=1)
         Group Key: "*VALUES*".column1
         ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.95 rows=76 width=16) (actual time=0.006..0.022 rows=76 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using table1_pkey on table1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=835) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=76)
         Index Cond: (id = "*VALUES*".column1)
         Buffers: shared hit=304
Planning Time: 0.437 ms
Execution Time: 0.389 ms
```

Looks like `VALUES ()` does some hashing and join to improve performance but not sure.

NOTE: In my practical use case, `id` is `uuid_generate_v4()` e.x. `d31cddc0-1771-4de8-ad41-e6c568b39a5d` but the column may not be indexed as such.
Also, I have a table of with `5-10 million records`.
Which way is for the better query performance?

Comment: The amount of data in your example is way too small for such differences in the query plan to really matter.  Unless your data is much larger, there is no reason to be concerned.  It looks like the use of `VALUES()` is incurring an extra step to remove duplicates.  That may or may not be useful for your actual query.

Comment: I have a table of with 5-10 million records. Added this info in the question.

Comment: Please run `explain (analyze, buffers)` on that table with both queries, then **[edit]** your question and add those execution plans.

Comment: Updated the question with an actual query result.

Comment: Do you have an index on `id`? If yes, the "array" solution should be able to use it if you cast the array to `uuid[]` rather then casting `id` to `text`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : added with ::uuid in both the queries. Please note that the id column may not be index as such

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "might not be index as such". Your plans clearly show that you have an index that includes the `id` column. The difference in performance between the two plans is only caused by the fact that the first one had to read some blocks from disk (`read=73`) , whereas in the second plan everything was in the buffer cache. If you run the first one multiple times, you probably get the same execution time as the second one. In either case both processed the same number of blocks (304). If everything is cached, I would actually expect the first plan to be faster.

Comment: I mean, the constraint is not for `id` column. It can be any column with having `::uuid` or `::text` fields. And those columns might not be indexed. E.x. `Class(id,student_id,...);` and  `Students(id,class_id,...);`. Here I would want to find `Class` rows with given list of `student_ids`.

Answer (score 0):

Both options seem reasonable. I would, however, suggest to avoid casting the column you filter on. Instead, you should cast the literal values to `uuid`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE id = ANY (ARRAY['00e289b0-1ac8-451f-957f-e00bc289148e'::uuid, ...]);
```

This should allow the database to take advantage of an index on column `id`.

Comment: Casting is not needed for the `VALUES ('00e289b0-1ac8-451f-957f-e00bc289148e')` method. Considering the 1 sec difference in the execution time, Is there any other way to validate or choose any one of them?

Comment: @impossible: what happens when you cast the array? What is the execution plan then?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : added with ::uuid in both the queries. Please note that the id column may not be index as such